# Disable use of object in a solution by devs

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Let's say i have an object that I don't want to be used by devs in our solution (because of misuse in the past). It is included in a .NET DLL so no possible way for me to remove. How can I disable the use of the object? Can I generate a compile warning/error to show to the devs?

Propably not possible (in code?), but maybe someone has a clever idea on how to solve this... Is this possible to configure in visual studio?

Comment: make it construtor private so on object will get created and then no one can use

Comment: As far as I know it is not directly possible in VS. You probably have to implement your own visual studio extension. Though that would not prevent them from running the compiler manually and just use notepad (or some other editor). @PranayRana solution is probably the best way to go.

Comment: A analyzer (like Rosalyn) can check the code while is written and aware the developer.

Comment: create custom compiler error somehow, or if in a devop pipeline or similar check code on check-in

Comment: What is `object`? How you use it (and probably want to continue using)? How others missuse it?

Comment: You could potentially use StyleCop and [write a custom rule](https://github.com/Visual-Stylecop/Visual-StyleCop/wiki/Authoring-a-Custom-StyleCop-Rule) to check for the object. Would probably be easier just to tell your devs not to use the object in question and look out for it in code reviews though.

Comment: I also tought about a private constructor, but since the object is located in another DLL and already has a public constructor, this isn't possible, I guess?

Comment: You could decorate the type with the [ObsoleteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=netframework-4.8). That's the common way to tell consumers not to use a type while still providing it for backwards compability.

Comment: As I said, the object is located in another DLL, thus not possible to add an attribute as well. The class is not partial and inheriting is not an option, since the inherited class is still available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using some form of gated commit, you could add a unit test that searches all your code files for the object name.

If not, you could write a small program to do the search and schedule it to run daily.

Really you should trust your programmers. Document what counts as 'misuse' and ask that you get to review any code that uses this object. Normal code reviews should be enough to spot anyone unaware of the rule.

Comment: I'm also not in favor of disabling it for the developers. But since code reviews are never done and no converntions are made, everyone can do whatever they want...